# Javascript code is executed in the reverse order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a part of my js:

```
window.location.reload();
$("#status").html('Try');
```

I expected the page to reload and then write "try" into the div "#status". But the reverse happens: The div "#status" is written into for a short period, then it disappears and then the page is reloaded where "#status" is empty again.

How do I get them to execute in the correct order?

Comment: It looks like it will always reload because each time the page loads it will reload again cozing the second code never to be executed. You can see the efect of status being changed but eventualy the page will keep reloading.

Comment: And, you're missing a semicolon

Comment: `reload()` just gets js to tell browser to resend a GET request to the current page, it doesn't wait until the reload finishes and continues to the next line of the script.

Comment: No he isn't missing a semicolon. They are only mandatory in inline event handlers

Comment: How can I reload the page and then write into a div ?

Comment: @Alegro write the content on page load instead..? like `$(window).load(function() { $('#status').html('try'); });`

Comment: @ SiGanteng, in that case the div will allways be writed by "Try". But, initially, it should be empty.

Comment: Fix the semicolon anyway. It looks better, and makes it easier for your colleagues to compress the code without having to retroactively go back and fix it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `window.location.reload()` in Firebug and see what happens.

Comment: @jmort253 - _"it easier for your colleagues to compress the code"_ - Do you compress code by hand? Any automatic JS minimiser that can't handle ASI is not worth using.

Comment: @nnnnnn - No, I don't compress code by hand but didn't really think about using a tool for that. I guess I just learned something new today. Thanks for pointing out the compression tool. With that said, good syntax is still good syntax and makes the code easier to read. There are many reasons to follow good coding standards and very few valid reasons not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.reload();` sends the event to the browser. So technically the event has been executed and it moves onto the next line.

What your comment above seems to imply that you want is more of a load once, and then add something to a div. I would maybe use the hashes in the URL to read this...

```
var pageHash = window.location.hash;
if(pageHash.indexOf("firstLoad") == -1) {
    //The page hasn't been loaded, so reload
    window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "#firstLoad";
} else {
    $("#status").html('Try');
}
```

Comment: thankyou, jamie, it's not a real solution (too long to explain), but it's  very usefull.

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a method you execute, you may see the effect of the change of html because the page did do start in time to reload. But this code is being executed with the right order. Its just that location.reload take more time to be executed then simply changing the innerHtml of an element.

Comment: what a stupid behaviour. I want to execute the code line by line, and not create a horse racing. It's so normally that next line cannot be executed before previous one is finished.

Comment: @Alegro - You have the wrong idea about how `window.location.reload();
` works. It reloads the whole page _including_ the JS, so the idea of continuing the current function _after_ the reload simply doesn't apply.

Comment: well its async my friend. when reload starts the rest of the code continues but the reload will occure when the browser is ready and will stop any execution

Comment: If you need your code to stop you can do this
window.location.reload();
return;
$("#status").html('Try');
But its usless since the rest of the code will never be executed anyway.

Comment: It seems, I must create a completely new page to get a three letters on a clean page. AnyWay, thanks for your efforts and explanation.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, window.location.reload(); is always at the end of any activity..

Comment: _"It seems, I must create a completely new page to get a three letters on a clean page."_ - Um - no, not necessarily. Why don't describe the effect you want to achieve from the user's point of view, and we can advise how such might be implemented.

Comment: @ nnnn I have a captcha with five images and a string. If user click on image named as string.value - the submit button is enabled and vice versa. I only want, if the user click on a wrong image - reload the whole page (security reasons) and give him a short message - "Try again".

Comment: hmmm sound like you can give him a message and then after 2-3 seconds make the redirect

Answer (score 0):

Alegro this could help in your case

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},5000); 
$("#status").html('Try');
```

So the message will get displayd and also after 5 seconds the page will get reloaded.